# Show the correct IAM user's sign-in link

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam

I am trying to create IAM users and after creating an user, I want to show the URL that user can use to login in AWS management console.

I am trying to do this with the code below, but I am having an issue.

Every time I create an user the AWS management console sign-in link changes and then when I print the URL and user access it I get a 404 error "The page you tried was not found".

Do you know how to create AWS management console profiles so users can access aws management console but have only one URL to sign in? Or other solution to fix this issue?

```
username = validField("Please enter your username: ")
password = validField("Please enter your password: ")
iam.create_user(username)
login = iam.create_login_profile(username, password)
url = iam.get_signin_url()
iam.create_account_alias("account-" + username)

print "You can acess aws managment console using this link: " + url
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the line causing your hassles:

```
iam.create_account_alias("account-" + username)
```

The Account Alias is for the AWS Account as a whole, not for an individual user. It will normally return a link like:

```
https://ALIAS.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/ec2
```

You should set the Alias to something easy to remember (eg company name) and issue this same link to all users.

Unfortunately, your code is modifying the Alias every time that a new user is created. There is only ONE alias for an account, not "one per user".